# Align text with images with equal spacing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to align the images and buttons equall with the header but it's not assigning. When I check in landscape, align getting mismatch. Here is my code.

When I checked in device, it's not fitting correctly.

Below is the code and output screen (My output and actual output which needed).

I used weight but it's not fitting correctly in all devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAlabaster">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Retailer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Hari sebelumnya" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Pindahkan ke hari" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="@string/route_plan_default_number"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="@string/route_plan_default_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorCyan"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:layout_width="86dp"
                        android:layout_height="29dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                        android:text="Selasa"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight=".2">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:layout_width="86dp"
                        android:layout_height="29dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_bottom"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Kamis"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

M**y Output:**

[image]

**Actual output:**

[image]

Comment: You should reconsider designing layout with contraint layout.Your design you have made it very complex to edit

Comment: @Anonymous I never used constraint layout. Is it possible to use the same layout using constraint layout? or need to modify entirely? can u suggest how?

Comment: Yes you need to modify it completely.constraint layout is advanced relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Here i have fixed the issue for you. But as the screen size will increase so does the size between your button and upper portion too. But your layout won't get messy. And if you want everything to remain fixed even on bigger screen sizes then you should use constraintLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Retailer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hari sebelumnya" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Pindahkan ke hari" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:weightSum="4">


        <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="sad234 234234"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/title_activity_test"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.5">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner_nothing_selected"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Selasa"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".5">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_add"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner_nothing_selected"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_edit_grey"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Kamis"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you. I have replaced the colors and ic_images with mine you will have to change them too by your own.

Comment: Thanks @Umair one issue which I am facing is, when the text is increased, the box gets moved and align is not proper. Eventhough singleLine is true and maxLines= 1 given.

Comment: @Walter to fix the box set layout_width = 0dp and set the weight then it's position will be fixed no matter the text size. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work. I redesign with your same xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAlabaster">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Retailer" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hari sebelumnya" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Pindahkan ke hari" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">




            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageViewx
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/route_plan_default_number"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="@string/route_plan_default_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorCyan"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                    android:text="Selasa"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:layout_width="86dp"
                    android:layout_height="29dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_bottom"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Kamis"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still I am having the design issue. Two buttons are improper when text gets increased.

Comment: The button text goes to the next line if it has a long text?

Comment: I mean, @+id/recycle_txt_acc_name.. when the name gets increase, the button box size shrinks.. so boxes doesn't look even..